# Proxy exposing multiple interfaces with Ninject.Extensions.Interception.Linfu

Tags: c#, proxy, ninject-interception, linfu

I'm using `Ninject.Extensions.Interception` (more specifically, `InterceptAttribute`) and `Ninject.Extensions.Interception.Linfu` proxying to implement a logging mechanism in my C# app, but I am facing some problems when a proxied class implements several interfaces.

I've a class which implements an interface and inherits from an abstract class.

```
public class MyClass : AbstractClass, IMyClass {
  public string SomeProperty { get; set; }
}


public class LoggableAttribute : InterceptAttribute { ... }

public interface IMyClass {
  public string SomeProperty { get; set; }
}

public abstract class AbstractClass {

  [Loggable]
  public virtual void SomeMethod(){ ... }
}
```

When I try to get an instance of MyClass from ServiceLocator, the *Loggable* attribute causes it to return a proxy.

```
var proxy = _serviceLocator.GetInstance<IMyClass>();
```

The problem is the proxy returned only recognizes the *AbstractClass* interface, exposing *SomeMethod()*. Consequentially, I receive an `ArgumentException` when I try to access the inexistent *SomeProperty*.

```
//ArgumentException
proxy.SomeProperty = "Hi";
```

In this case, is there a way of using mixin or some other technique to create a proxy exposing multiple interfaces?

Thanks

Paulo

Answer (score 0):

I ran in a similar problem and i did not found a elegant solution with only ninject means. So i tackled the problem with a more basic pattern from OOP: composition.

Applied to your problem something like this would be my suggestion:

```
public interface IInterceptedMethods
{
    void MethodA();
}

public interface IMyClass
{
    void MethodA();
    void MethodB();
}

public class MyInterceptedMethods : IInterceptedMethods
{
    [Loggable]
    public virtual void MethodA()
    {
        //Do stuff
    }
}

public class MyClass : IMyClass
{
    private IInterceptedMethods _IInterceptedMethods;
    public MyClass(IInterceptedMethods InterceptedMethods)
    {
        this._IInterceptedMethods = InterceptedMethods;
    }
    public MethodA()
    {
        this._IInterceptedMethods.MethodA();
    }
    public Method()
    {
        //Do stuff, but don't get intercepted
    }
}
```